# Reactjs/Kioskboard warning: MIME type ("text/html") is not a valid MIME type for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I think my scripts aren't working because of the warning I'm getting in my dev console:
The script from "http://localhost:3000/keyboard/kioskboard-aio-2.3.0.min.js" was loaded, although its MIME type ("text/html") is not a valid MIME type for JavaScript.
These are my Filepaths:

[image]

I feel like i tried everything to fix this but I just can't figure out why its not working.
Any tips would be helpful.

This is the code I want to execute:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './assets/style.css'
import myData from "./assets/slogans.json";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import KioskBoard from 'kioskboard';

const SloganEnterScreen = (props) => {
    const [slogan, updateSlogan] = useState("");

    const handleContinue = () => {
        props.onStart()
        props.updateSlogan(slogan)
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        // Update the slogan state as the user types
        updateSlogan(event.target.value);
    };


return(
    <>
        <Helmet>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/style.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/keyboard/kioskboard-aio-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
        </Helmet>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Bildgenerator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css" />
        <div id="base">
            <button onClick={props.onExit} className="x-button" />
            <main>
                <div className="page">
                    <div className="title">
                        <strong>Eingabe</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sub-title big-text">
                        Dein kreativer Slogan!
                        <br />
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="content-full">
                            <div style={{ height: "2em" }} />
                            <div className="row">
                                <input
                                    style={{ width: "85%" }}
                                    type="text"
                                    className="text-input js-kioskboard-input"
                                    data-kioskboard-type="all"
                                    data-kioskboard-placement="bottom"
                                    data-kioskboard-specialcharacters="true"
                                    placeholder="Tippe hier um etwas einzugeben"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <button onClick={handleContinue} style={{ width: "15%" }}>Fertig</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="progress">
                        <div />
                        <div />
                        <div />
                        <div className="current" />
                        <div />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </>

);
};
export default SloganEnterScreen;
```

I want to import the Kioskboard scripts to use them with my website.
I'm using Reactjs Server with npm start. Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the following steps for successful integration of Kioskboard into your React application:

- Confirm correct script paths in the Helmet component.
- Verify the execution order of kioskboard-aio-2.3.0.min.js and main.js.
- Validate React Helmet configuration and eliminate duplicate stylesheet links.
- Check browser console for loading or execution errors.
- Confirm absence of unmet external dependencies.

These are some possiblities, Please verify these things.